# Why scala pattern matching is not equivalent to isInstanceOf

Tags: scala, casting, pattern-matching

I believed for a long time that this two constructions is equivalent:

```
if (myVar.isInstanceOf[MyType]) myVar.asInstanceOf[MyType].doSomething
```

and

```
myVar match {
  case my : MyType => my.doSomething
  case _ => {}
}
```

But suddenly I've found that I get type error while trying to match `Number` value to the `Double` type, but `asInstanceOf[Double]` works fine. WTF is happening?

---

simple example for scala REPL

```
val d = 3.5
val n : Number = d
n.isInstanceOf[Double]
```

works fine:

```
Boolean = true
```

but

```
n match {
  case x : Double => println("double")
  case _ => println("not a double")
}
```

produces type error:

```
:11: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
found   : Double
required: Number
          case x : Double => println("double")
```

Comment: can you post the example with `Number` and the `Double`?

Answer (score 1):

`scala.Double` is not inherited from `java.lang.Number` but from `AnyVal`. 
You want to match on `java.lang.Double`:

```
n match {
  case x : java.lang.Double => println("double")
  case _                    => println("not a double")
}
```

When using

```
val d = 3.5
val n : Number = d  // implicit conversion from scala.Double to java.lang.Double
```

`scala.Double` is implicitly converted to `java.lang.Double` during assignment to `n`

Comment: Don't you have it backwards in your first sentence?

Comment: Not really. n is really a java.lang.Double - match works, tested :)

Comment: Yes, that's what you meant, but you did write of **`scala`** `.Double`

Comment: But why in this case `isInstanceOf` works normally? It should also detect type incompatibility

Comment: Looks like compiler intricacies to me, but if you try `println(n.getClass)`, you will see `java.lang.Double`

Comment: java.lang.Double differs from scala.lang.Double. And possibility for `isInstanceOf` of using implicits gives be nightmares

Comment: In these kind of situations I use imports such as `import java.lang.{Double => JDouble}`. And then I can explicitly show java doubles as JDouble